# Where does HealthKit stores its data?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Health related data for a user is a privacy thing and its need to be very secure i.e. it needs to be stored in secure place. For example, while I was watching Apple's official video on Finger print unlock, they told that finger print data is stored at place where it is impossible to hack. So, for a curiosity, I have a question in mind that where these data are securely stored?

I have had a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/protecting_user_privacy) link from Apple Documentation but could not found the information on it. One thing I have figured out is that data are encrypted and stored but where?

Does anyone has idea on the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, NSUserDefaults is simple and effective for saving small, simple bits of data, like NSNumbers or NSStrings, to your device’s file system. But this data is in no way stored securely as hackers can access it pretty easily from the device.

You have figured out that sensitive data are encrypted. But you need to find the answer where it need to be stored. The Answer is:

> **Keychain Services**:Apple has provided the Keychain Services API to deal with this problem and help developers build apps that safely handle passwords and other sensitive information.
>
> > **Now the question might rase why??** and the answer is: 
> >     Keychain is great because data encryption automatically is taken care of before it is stored in the file system so there is no need to waste time building encryption algorithms.

You can go through this link for better explanation.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services

Comment: Okay, so we can just access health data programmatically (after user gives permission) ?

Comment: And does Apple stores Health data in `Keychain service` behind the scene?

Comment: Apple has a separate [tag:HealthkitStore] for that purpose. Please go through the following link for better understanding.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/protecting_user_privacy

Answer (score 1):

Apple describes the security attributes of various iOS features in this [document](https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf). To quote:

> This data is stored in Data Protection class Protected Unless Open.
>   Access to the data is relinquished 10 minutes after device locks, and
>   data becomes accessible the next time user enters their passcode or
>   uses Touch ID or Face ID to unlock the device.

Read the "Encryption and Data Protection" section of the document to learn more about Data Protection. Any app can use the "Protected Unless Open" data protection class for its persistent data.